# OpenJDK 64 bit Java 1.6 : Doesn't support dot in CLI system properties?

Tags: command-line, properties, system, java

The version of Java is printed below:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

When passing a property like so:

```
java -Dmy.property=value -jar my.jar
```

..it fails to resolve in the code:

```
System.getProperty("my.property") // => null
```

However using an underscore in place of the dot works fine:

```
// CLI
java -Dmy_property=value -jar my.jar
// In the code:
System.getProperty("my_property") // => "value"
```

Isn't this non-standard behaviour?

In case it's relevant, the JAR is being built via Maven and the `maven-assembly-plugin` is being used to bundle dependencies into the JAR.

Comment: That seems strange since there are a lot of different standard options with dot (like `-Djava.net.ssl.truststore=somekeystore.jks`).

Comment: Tell me about it! I'm trying to figure out what's going wrong, will post here when it's figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I was using the improper format `java -jar my.jar -Dmy.prop=value` rather than the correct `java -Dmy.prop=value -jar my.jar`. But I realised this early on and amended my parameter ordering.

However, it turns out when editing the monolithic chain of commands I was editing (with this `java -jar` command in-line amongst them) I mistakenly created another incorrect command structure: `java -jar -Dmy.prop=value my.jar`.

The first time I used underscores the command was rewritten, thus inadvertently fixing this latter incorrect parameter structure.

So the moral of the story is: ensure you have `-jar my.jar` right at the end of your `java` command. Always!

Answer (score 0):

Java supports dots in property names when you set them like that.

A couple of possible explanations:

- The *actual* command being executed is different to that.  Maybe there's a bug in your launch script or something.  (Try using "set -x" to get the shell to tell you what the actual command options are.)
- Some other part of your application is unsetting that particular property before the call to `getProperty` you are looking at.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond. Your first suggestion was correct - see my answer below.